# How to delete the newline in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter currently has auto line breaks. How can I remove auto line breaks in dart (flutter)?
I want to know the way to delete them.

This is the code

```
import 'dart:math';

void main(){
  List<int> code = [];
  while (true) {
    var Roomcode = Random().nextInt(10);
    code.add(Roomcode);

  if (code.length == 6) break;
  }

  code.sort();

  for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
         print('${code.toString().split(",")[i]}');
  }
      setState(() {});
}


void setState(Null Function() param0) {
}
```

[1
2
2
3
7
7]
This is the result of this code.
I want to change that to
[122377]

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap your widget with `Expanded()` to break a new line in Flutter.
if you are using `Text('This is line 1\nThis is line 2')`